# How is enumerated() constant time O(1)?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, big-o

I was looking at the documentation for `enumerated()` on the `Array` type and noticed that it says:

> Complexity: O(1)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated

This doesn't seem make sense, as traversing an array would be linear time - `O(n)` - since the length of the array is not known. `enumerated()` would have to traverse an array in order to return the `EnumeratedSequence`. How is this function constant time complexity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Creating an `EnumeratedSequence` comes down to [initializing](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L130) its iterator. The latter is done in two steps:

- Have a pointer to the base collection or sequence on which `enumerated()` is called.
- Initialize the internal variable `_count` to `0`

The time taken to do these two steps doesn't change with the number of elements in the collection/sequence.

Looping through the elements of an `EnumeratedSequence` is equivalent to calling [`.next()`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/da61cc8cdf7aa2bfb3ab03200c52c4d371dc6751/stdlib/public/core/Algorithm.swift#L146) on the iterator of the `EnumeratedSequence`. Which creates (on demand) a tuple `let result = (offset: _count, element: b)` as long as there are elements in the base collection/sequence (hence the guard statement), and increment the `_count += 1`.

To recapitulate: Creating an enumerated sequence is O(1), but looping through all the elements is of course O(n).

Comment: Nice explanation!